# Go build with another glibc

Tags: go, build, glibc, dynamic-linking, libc

I have installed another version of GLIBC and want to compile Golang code against this new GLIBC.

I have tried the following command for dynamic compilation:

```
go build --ldflags '-linkmode external -L /path/to/another_glibc/
```

But when I run ldd `"go_executable"`, it still shows linked to default glibc.

**Output:**

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff29da7000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f128a93c000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f128ad06000)
```

**Expected Output:**

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff45fa7000)
libc.so.6 => /another_glibc/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5cd2067000)
/another_glibc/ld-2.29.so => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5cd2420000)
```

What is missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before doing `go build`
Set

> CGO_LDFLAGS

Dynamic:

```
export CGO_LDFLAGS="-Xlinker -rpath=/path/to/another_glibc/lib"
```

Static:

```
export CGO_LDFLAGS="-Xlinker -rpath=/path/to/another_glibc/lib -static"
```

CGO_LDFLAGS lets you set GCC-like ld flags for Go.

Answer (score 34):

This is not an answer to the question, just a warning:

If you, like me, came here because you were compiling to deploy on another machine and got "version `GLIBC_2.32' not found" (or similar), but you were not intentionally using CGo, stop here.

Go on Linux dynamically links C libraries to have faster and smaller builds, but it is able to supplement them for example when cross-compiling.

You can do `export CGO_ENABLED=0` to disable CGo and get rid of the dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

[bitbyter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55455448/8316315) is not correct for the dynamic case because it requires that the system dynamic linker is compatible with the non-system glibc, which is unlikely. You can set the dynamic linker like this:

```
export CGO_LDFLAGS="-Xlinker -rpath=/path/to/another_glibc/lib64"
CGO_LDFLAGS="$CGO_LDFLAGS -Xlinker --dynamic-linker="/path/to/another_glibc/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"
```

The dynamic linker name is specific to the architecture, so you have to research its name.

Comment: I did not face the dynamic linker incompatibility issue, hence didn't think further. Thanks for the next step to try out in case the command in my answer doesn't work.